# Website not rendering properly on boss's computer / browser, but all others seem to work fine. Help?

Tags: html, css, debugging

I'm a university student, and just built my first website for an internship. We are approaching the launch of the site, however during my debugging process I've found that of all places, it doesn't work on my boss's machine and browser combination. She uses a Vista OS and internet explorer 7 for a browser. I know IE7 is outdated, but according to broswershots.org IE7 will still render the site mostly correct on an XP operating system.

The main page of the site is accessible [here](http://www.mainewindependence.org/dev/test/index.html)

Here are screenshots of what happens with the Vista/IE7 combo:

[image: http://imgur.com/a/DB0s6]

[image: http://imgur.com/a/DB0s6]

Please let me know what you think, as any ideas would be extremely helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Is this different if the window isn't maximized on your boss's computer?  Would changing the screen resolution on your boss's computer make it appear correctly?  Does your boss have unusual browser settings in comparision to the browser settings on your machine?  Do you get the same problem using Firefox on your machine, or your boss's computer? This might point you in the right direction.

Comment: I'd take the code over to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: not to be mean but the problem is probably at the core of your code layout wise. That green box should be able to accommodate all the text if it doesn't have a height set. Setting height to auto should fix that and then u should use padding and such to space borders of the box from text etc. I would also almost say the same for the navigation (though with width) but there could be many other things wrong with that

Answer (score 0):

"IE7 will still render the site mostly correct"

Sadly, no. IE has a long history of being crap and ignoring web standards. IE6 was notorious for this. IE7 a pain. IE8 a bummer and IE9 is mostly now just a small annoyance.

Bottom line is that you likely have IE7 bugs appearing. It's not necessarily indicative to bad markup or CSS, but rather just problems with IE7.

The typical solution is to use IE conditional comments to render a unique class name to the BODY tag. You can then over-ride the standard CSS just for a particular version of IE7 to bend it into submission:

```
<!--[if !IE]> -->
    <body>
<!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]> 
    <body id="IE9">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
    <body id="IE8">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
    <body id="IE7">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
    <body id="IE6">
<![endif]-->
```

And then in your css you can do this:

```
.myClass {...standard styles...}
#IE7 .myClass {...ugly hack just for IE7...}
#IE6 .myClass {...ugly hack just for IE6...}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Please excuse my confusion, but I'm not exactly sure what you mean here... Do I need to restyle a whole "translation" of the site just for IE7 (/maybe each version of IE)?

Comment: Also, how does the above code work? I've never programmed conditional statements into html

Comment: There's typically going to be a few issues in each version of IE that you will have to deal with. You won't need to reset every single CSS style declaration...hopefully just a few of them. As for the above code, it works because IE supports it. A normal browser will just have `<body>` but if it's a version of IE, one of the alternative body tags will be rendered instead with the appropriate class name.

Comment: Actually, taking a second look at your site, it looks like you haven't designed the layout to accomodate different font sizes. You don't have absolute control over font sizes so you need to make sure your layout accommodates larger and smaller text with proper wrapping.

Comment: @ your second comment: how do I accomplish that? If I don't know the size of text a client's browser will read, how do I accommodate it with proper wrapping?  thanks for the continued help :)

Comment: text wraps by default. So assume you will have more text or larger text than will fit and let your design reflow as needed. It's not really a simple how-to but rather a holistic approach to web design in general. Remember that web design isn't about dictating a visual design, but rather merely suggesting a visual design.

Answer (score 0):

In your boss's browser, go to Tools, Internet Options, Accessiblity.

She may have checkboxes checked that override font settings.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately this was not the issue. :/